# unable to run C program using VSC

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, path, environment-variables

I am trying to run a Hello World in C language using Visual Studio Code.the problem is when typing in the Terminal gcc filename.c , it is telling me that The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program and it is telling to check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, and to verify that the path is correct and try again.
I am using Windows btw so what is the solution? :)

I tried to find fixex for the problem in chatGPT but also didnt help
this is what happened by the way:
gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- gcc test.c
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: VIsual Studio Code is just an IDE, a program for editing code. You'll need to install gcc separately,, mingw I think it is for Windows?

Comment: In order to use C or C++ with Visual Studio Code, you must install the C/C++ extension and also install a compiler. See [this official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) for further information.

Comment: gcc's not in your `$PATH` (possibly not even installed).  That's true of Windows and the various POSIX-like platforms.